# Rest Assured: ignoring certificate errors

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured

The certificate I get back from the server has an error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: X.509 Certificate is incomplete:
> SubjectAlternativeName extension MUST be marked critical when subject
> field is empty

I found out that using relaxedHTTPSValidation should do the trick of ignoring the certificate errors.

So I tried to use it like this:

```
@When("^Get All Applications Request Executed$")
public void getAllApplicationsRequestExecuted() {

    response =
    given()
        .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
        .log().all()
        .spec(testContext().getRequestSpec())
    .when()
        .get("application/api/virtual-services/") //Send the request along with the resource
    .then()
        .extract()
        .response();

    testContext().setResponse(response);
}
```

Also, I added this @Before hook:

```
@Before
public void setUseRelaxedHTTPSValidation(){
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
}
```

But I see no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using via configuration like this:

```
@When("^Get All Applications Request Executed$")
public void getAllApplicationsRequestExecuted() {
    given()
        .config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames()))
        .log().all()
        .spec(testContext().getRequestSpec())
    .when()
        .get("application/api/virtual-services/") //Send the request along with the resource
    .then()
        .extract()
        .response();

    testContext().setResponse(response);
}
```